# MVC - Arquivo php intermediário na relação da View e do Controller

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

Olá, pessoal.
Eu estava refletindo sobre a existência de uma etapa da relação da estrutura do meu projeto.

A organização do meu projeto está da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[1 ] Ao acessar a página o usuário pode acessar tanto pelo endereço normal (ex. `curso.php`) ou com parâmetros (ex. `curso.php?curso=sistema_informacao`). No caso do acesso por endereço normal, normalmente é acessado pelo botão que tem no arquivo `index.php`. 
A partir da ação do usuário o arquivo `curso.php` faz uma verificação se foi passado algum parâmetro, em que normalmente é passado via `ajax` na etapa [3].

[2] Assim que o arquivo `curso.php` finaliza a verificação de parâmetros, ele chama o arquivo `view_curso.php`. O endereço permanecerá como `.../curso.php`

[3] Através de ações do usuário o javascript faz POST via `ajax` para o arquivo `curso.php` e um dos parâmetros que é enviado é chamado de `opcao`, assim o `curso.php` sabe qual função do controller deve chamar, etapa [4].

```
function pesquisar(){
    var curso = documento.getElementById("id_curso").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "curso.php",
        data: {
            "curso": curso,
            'opcao': 'pesquisar_disciplinas'
        }
    });
}
```

[4] O controller verifica a ação e se os parâmetros estiverem corretos ele chama a classe que executará aquela ação.

[5] Nesse exemplo, a ação sendo um select, então o controller chama o `model_curso.php`.

[6] O `model_curso.php` retorna o resultado para o controller.

[7] O controller verifica, e nesse exemplo ele chama o arquivo `view_painel_curso.php` com os resultados do `model_curso.php`.

A dúvida que eu tenho é se realmente há a necessidade de existir o arquivo `curso.php`.

Basicamente, o arquivo `curso.php` é um intermediário da view e do controller, e tem como função fazer um filtro do que está sendo solicitado pela view e passar para o controller que então dita quem realizará executar.

Existe alguma variação do MVC que utiliza essa arquitetura que estou utilizando ou podemos dizer que ainda sim é o MVC? Vocês usam alguma estrutura similar?

**curso.php**

```
<?php

# Importar bibliotecas e classes
require_once "../require.php";

# Importar controlador
require_once "./controllers.php";

// mostrar exceções de banco de dados
$APP->getDBLink()->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

# exigir que usuário esteja logado
$APP->requireLoggedUser(true);

# Inicializar o objeto controlador
$Ctrl = new \curso\Controller($APP);

# método da requisição
$reqmethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if( $reqmethod == "POST" ) {
    $opcao          = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "opcao");

    // salvar disciplina
    if ($opcao == "salvar_curso"){
        $Ctrl->salvarCurso(['POST' => $_POST]);
   // pesquisar curso
    } elseif($opcao == "pesquisar_disciplinas"){
        $Ctrl->getDisciplinas($_POST);

    }
} else {

    $curso = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "curso");
    $disciplina = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "disciplina");

    if(isset($curso)) {

        $APP->requireLoggedUser(true);

        # Define qual parte do controlador vai usar
        $content = function() use($Ctrl) {
            // 
            $Ctrl->pesquisar(['GET' => $_GET ]);
        };
    } else {
        $content = function() use($Ctrl){
            $Ctrl->indexAction('view_curso');
        };
    }

    # qual template HTML
    $qual_template = 'basico2';

    # título da página
    $title = 'Cursos Faculdade';

    $options['css']['files'][] = '<link href="static/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">';
    $options['js_files'][] = '<script src="./static/assets/moment/moment.js"></script>';
    $options['js_files'][] = '<script src="./static/assets/moment/moment-with-locales.js"></script>';
    $options['js_files'][] = '<script type="text/javascript" src="static/curso.js"></script>';

    $options['favicon'] = '<link  id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/imgs/icone.png" type="text/css" />';

    # chamar o template 
    $APP->printTemplate( $qual_template, $title, $content, $options );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"- Existe alguma variação do MCV que utiliza essa arquitetura que estou utilizando ou podemos dizer que ainda sim é o MCV? Vocês usam alguma estrutura similar?"*

Vou presumir que o seu real **problema** é sobre estruturar seu código a fim de seguir o padrão *MVC*. Pois perguntas do tipo: *"- Vocês usam alguma estrutura similar?"* acabam não sendo um real problema, como definido na [central de ajuda da comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Digamos que: você está fugindo da teoria do padrão *MVC* no momento em que você *intermedia* as ações de cada um dos seus setores (Model, View e Controller).

Veja que seu arquivo `curso.php` está misturando o serviço de vários setores do *MVC*: Iniciando a aplicação, chamando o controlador, chamando o modelo e renderizando. Veja:

```
# Importar bibliotecas e classes
require_once "../require.php";

# Importar controlador
require_once "./controllers.php";

// ...

# Inicializar o objeto controlador
$Ctrl = new \curso\Controller($APP);

# método da requisição
$reqmethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

// ...

# chamar o template 
$APP->printTemplate( $qual_template, $title, $content, $options );
```

Quando desenvolvemos uma aplicação baseada no padrão *MVC*, criamos o conhecido *bootstrap* (também conhecido como *init*), que é uma classe que "*chama*" o controlador certo, conforme a requisição do usuário.

Como pude observar, você está chamando o controlador/método no arquivo `curso.php`, o que faz com que a tal *bootstrap* seja esse arquivo.

Como solução, posso te sugerir o seguinte:

Desenvolva sua *bootstrap* de forma que seja dinâmica. O controlador/método pode ser passado via parâmetro (Ex.: `http://meu.site.com/index.php?controlador=cursos&metodo=ver`) ou via *URL amigável* (Ex.: `http://meu.site.com/cursos/ver` - requer configuração específica do Apache / `.htaccess`).

Na maioria dos diagramas de MVC isso é omitido, sendo considerado como parte do *controller*. Mas não é! Ela é responsável por chamar o *controller* e o método certo, como já dito.

Outra coisa que você pode considerar é utilizar um *AutoLoader* para carregar suas classes. Recomendo o [PSR-4: Autoloader - PHP-FIG](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Visto que não é o perguntado, não vou entrar em mais detalhes sobre o padrão *MVC* (como estruturação, oq desenvolver em cada lugar e etc). Fiz questão de explicar essa parte pois se refere ao contexto da pergunta. Contudo, sugiro que aprofunde seu estudo/desenvolvimento em cima disso que lhe passei.